# How do i make a dropdown menu and call it via jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have these sets of buttons
[image]

By clicking on any one button it I want to get a drop down menu like this :
[image]

How do I call the menu via jQuery? 
I tried using a form method but it did not work. Later when I get this value, I want it to append it to a separate div for display.

My button code :

```
<img id="analysis" class="normal_button" title="select analysis" src="buttons/analysis.png">
```

My jquery code :

```
jQuery("#analysis").click(function(){
   alert("hello world");

   });
});
```

Thanks for the helps.

Comment: my button code 

<img id="webtronics_analysis" class="normal_button" title="select analysis" src="buttons/analysis.png">

Comment: Can you create SO Snippet for better understanding what you want?

Comment: I'm quite sure that code is not your best effort in solving your problem. Show your code you used to create a Sortable Dropdown (with checkbox list items), Show your code where you've initially made it hidden, show the code you used to show it on click - than ask for help. Read [ask]

Comment: Also you say... *"later when I get this value"* ...what value, dear? In your image I can see a list with load of checkboxes. Clarify your thoughts.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for, https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create the select menu in your html and put a `display: none` onto it. Once you've done that you simply use a `jQuery click`  event. You can use the `toggle()` method so that if the user clicks the `button` again it will hide it.

```
$('#analysis').click(function(){ 
       $('.selectmenu').toggle();
       // You can also use other fade methods $('.selectmenu').slideDown();

 });
```